# Sharing ViewModel in ViewPager using parent fragment as owner

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation, dagger-hilt

I have a parent Fragment A with Fragment B and Fragment C inside a ViewPager. I want to share Fragment's A ViewModel within Fragment B and Fragment C.

This was my approach which seemed intuitive at first:

In parent Fragment A which contains ViewPager, I create my viewModel like this:

```
val viewModel by viewModels<SharedViewModel>()
```

...

```
@HiltViewModel
class SharedViewModel @Inject constructor(
    stateHandle: SavedStateHandle
) {

   val myArgument = stateHandle.get<Boolean>("myArgument")
   ...

 }
```

My ViewPager Fragment's B and C are trying to access same `SharedViewModel` instance like this:

```
   private val sharedViewModel by viewModels<SharedViewModel>(
        ownerProducer = { requireParentFragment() }
    )
```

Everything works fine, except when the process is destroyed, my `savedStateHandle` in the `SharedViewModel` does not retain arguments passed by navigation component. Doing this in `SharedViewModel` returns null and `savedStateHandle` is empty.

```
val myArgument = stateHandle.get<Boolean>("myArgument")
```

Does someone know why is this happening? Using `activityViewModels` seems to fix this, but I do not fully understand why.